Mathfonts for numbers in xelatex
I am using xelatex for writing my thesis and I need an alternative font for numbers because I have already used bold numbers (bm package), numbers with hats and regular math font numbers to denote other things and I need them not to be confused. I looked at Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List table 348 but it seems to me that dsserif doesn't work (code below). I can't set a math font with \setmathfont either (I tried GFS Artemisia with \setmathfont{GFS Artemisia} in the preamble and inside the main document. According to my computer's font manager the font is installed). It gives error Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \setmathfont.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dsserif}
\setmainfont[Mapping=TeX-text]{Liberation Serif}
%\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,mathabx,bm, stmaryrd,ebproof}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{greek,russian}
\usepackage{ucharclasses}
\usepackage{phonetic}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\begin{document}

$\mathbb{123456789}$

\end{document}

So the question is... could someone explain why the above code doesn't work and suggest me a solution (ideally using mathbb font or a similar one)? The \setmathfont command isn't quite suitable for what I need (although curious why it doesn't work).
The example code lists all packages that I think may cause problems.
EDIT AFTER MICO'S ANSWER WAS SUBMITTED: Just to clarify... setting another math font was an alternative for the mathbb font in order to denote 0,1 etc with a distinctive symbol other than that offered by liberation serif. But I wasn't satisfied with the outcome and I quickly abandoned the idea, after testing though how to insert a math font and failing in the try. It turned out to be a helpful ambiguity.

In order to use \setmathfont, you must load the unicode-math package, which loads fontspec automatically. However, are you sure that GFS Artemisia is actually a math font Ias opposed to a text font)?

also don't use xunicode or xltxtra with current xelatex

I didn't notice that it needed unicode-math thank you! Now the \setmathfont command works but there are conflicts with amssymb package (not really a problem because I probably won't change the math font). To be honest I am not sure if it is a math font. I know it supports math just like Asana Math. I can't discern.

Could you @DavidCarlisle explain why? because I use the template that my school is asking us to use and it was like this. I haven't run into errors yet with these packages.

How old is your school's template? When was it last updated?

Math font packages such as amsymb must be loaded before unicode-math.

For sure, Asana Math is a math font. Incidentally, no need to specify the option Mapping=TeX-text, unless your TeX distribution is at least a dozen years old.

@Mico probably it was created in 2018. The conflicts keep going with other packages unfortunately.  Don't bother. I won't load unicode-math

@ΝικολέταΣεβαστού - If you don't load unicode-math and don't issue a suitable \setmathfont directive, LuaLaTeX will simply employ the default math font, which happens to be Latin Modern Math. Unfortunately ,  Latin Modern Math doesn't mesh well at all, visually speaking, with Liberation Serif. What's your reason for apparently not wanting to use Asana Math?

Up till now I found no problem without declaring the math font. I don't know if I must declare one, but it seems as if Liberation Serif did the job nicely enough.

My main problem is how to load the \mathbb font for numbers.

Liberation Serif is a text font, not a math font. As I wrote, LuaLaTeX's default math font is Latin Modern Math. If you believe you can live with this combination, more power to you. Regarding your new "main problem" -- Is something keeping you from loading mathtools and amssymb?

I am sorry but I can't understand your question. I have updated the code. Maybe it is more clear now what I want to correct.

Please re-read the earlier comments. One of them said that math font packages such asamssymb (and, by extension, amsmath and mathtools) must be loaded before fontspec. That's not what your code does.

I corrected it but the problem remains.

Please run the code to see that the problem is not just the conflicts. Even if I change the order as suggested I can't get a \mathbb{0} to compile. The pdf isn't produced. this was my main problem from the beginning and I understand I didn't explain it right.

It would appear that the dsserif package is incompatible with XeLaTeX. Incidentally, do you have a reason for running XeLaTeX instead of LuaLaTeX, other than the fact that the school template was set up for use with XeLaTeX? The latter would appear to be compatible with dsserif. :-)

To be honest I am not familiar with Luatex. One other reason (except for the template being originally written in xelatex) is that I use one specific guide in greek that introduces xelatex and I have no guide for Luatex. What changes should I make? I have many more packages that aren't in the MWE and I don't know if all the others be compatible. Is there another solution except using dsserif?

xltxtra dates from the ealiest days before xetex was officially supported by latex, it defines some things not needed and some other things that were not incorporated so it just doesn't do anything very useful now similarly xunicode just installs a non standard accent handling, from a time before xetex was officially supported, so it's likely incompatible with modern font packages and is anyway not needed except for specific legacy cases of documents using the command names it defines

The template you're using requires XeLaTeX. Unfortunately, the dsserif package appears to be incompatible with XeLaTeX. Fortunately, though, dsserif is compatible with LuaLaTeX.
No information you've provided so far indicates that you mustn't use LuaLaTeX. For sure, with just a few minor changes to your code (see below), your sample code can be made to work well under LuaLaTeX.
About the text font: Liberation Serif is a font that's metrically identical to Times Roman, while being free (in all senses of the word). Unfortunately, I don't have Liberation Serif installed on my system. I do have FreeSerif, though, which is also a Times Roman clone that provides Cyrillic glyphs, which I gather you need because Russian is one of the language choices you've specified.
If you choose to go down the LuaLaTeX route, I recommend you load the newtxmath package, which provides a Times Roman math font clone. And, if you load the newtxmath package, be sure to load dsserif after newtxmath.

% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
%%%%\usepackage{xltxtra} % not for use under LuaLaTeX

%%\usepackage{amsmath} % is loaded automatically by 'mathtools'
%\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{mathtools} % superset of 'amsmath' package

\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,bm} 
% Do you really need mathabx, stmaryrd, and ebproof ??
%%%%\usepackage{xunicode}

\usepackage{fontspec}
%%%%\setmainfont[Mapping=TeX-text]{Liberation Serif}
   % 'Mapping=TeX-text' has been the default for years
   % I don't have 'Liberation Serif' on my system
\setmainfont{FreeSerif} % Times Roman text font clone with lots of glyphs
\usepackage{newtxmath} % optional: employ Times Roman math font clone
 
\usepackage{dsserif} % load *after* 'newtxmath'

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{greek,russian}

\usepackage{phonetic} % are you sure you need this package?

\begin{document}

0123456789 \quad 
\textit{abc \dots\ xyz} \quad 
\textrussian{Привет, мир.}

$\mathbb{123456789} \quad 
abc\dots xyz \quad 
\sum\prod\int \displaystyle\sum\prod\int$

\end{document}


Thank you very very very much! It is fixed (I tried Liberation serif instead of free serif and it works too). And a special thank you for the comments around packages. They were very helpful. I will try to keep them in mind.
Yes I need the packages stmaryrd, ebproof and mathabx because my thesis is for the consistency proofs of PA. stmaryrd is needed for double square brackets, ebproof for proof trees and mathabx for \dotdiv.
Phonetic was in the template originally and just didn't bother searching why. After 70 pages of pdf document I found no collisions so it stayed intact.

if you are using Unicode math fonts which all have double square brackets etc, you do not need legacy 8 bit fonts with tex specific encodings such as stmaryrd to use those characters @ΝικολέταΣεβαστού

I have found another solution that offers some greek letters too. It uses bboldx package that wasn't included in the  Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List in table 348. The only problem is that it is a text font. But the guide of  bboldx package suggests a solution.
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{mathtools} % superset of 'amsmath' package

\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,bm} %math font packages such asamssymb (and, by extension, amsmath and mathtools) must be loaded before fontspec

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Liberation Serif} % Or freeserif which is Times Roman text font clone with lots of glyphs
\usepackage{newtxmath} % here it not optional since stmaryrd isn't loaded. It will give an error otherwise.

\usepackage{bboldx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{greek,russian}
\newcommand{\bbzero}{\mathbb{0}}%numbers are supported in mathmode
\newcommand{\bbone}{\mathbb{1}}

%\usepackage{phonetic} % are you sure you need this package?
\newcommand{\bbomega}{\text{\textbb{\char 127}}}%lowercase greek letters are not supported in mathmode directly. The \text command is needed.
\begin{document}
    
    0123456789 \quad 
    \textit{abc \dots\ xyz} \quad 
    \textrussian{Привет, мир.}
    
    $\mathbb{0123456789} \quad 
    abc\dots xyz \quad 
    \sum\prod\int \displaystyle\sum\prod\int$

$\bbomega$ %lowercase greek letter
$\llbracket \tau \rrbracket$%Indeed \llbracket and \rrbracket are  supported with newtxmath package without stmaryrd.
\end{document}

However mathabx conflicts with newtxmath. So here is another solution (happy to be corrected if mathabx can get along with newtxmath or if my solution can be improved).
%Typeset using LuaLaTeX
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{mathtools} % superset of 'amsmath' package
    
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,bm,mathabx,stmaryrd, ebproof} 

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif} % Or freeserif which is Times Roman text font clone with lots of glyphs


\usepackage{bboldx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{greek,russian}
\newcommand{\bbzero}{\mathbb{0}}
\newcommand{\bbone}{\mathbb{1}}


\newcommand{\bbomega}{\text{\textbb{\char 127}}}
\begin{document}
    
    0123456789 \quad 
    \textit{abc \dots\ xyz} \quad 
    \textrussian{Привет, мир.}
    
    $\mathbb{0123456789} \quad 
    abc\dots xyz \quad 
    \sum\prod\int \displaystyle\sum\prod\int$
    
    $\bbomega$ %least countable ordinal

    $\llbracket \tau \rrbracket$
    $\oplus$
\end{document}


TeX Gyre DejaVu Math provides doublestruck numbers. DejaVu Serif fonts are somewhat similar to Liberation Serif fonts in their look.

What is the main font of your document? Liberation Serif?

Yes the main font is liberation serif. I tried your suggestion with TeX Gyre DejaVu Math locally (i.e. didn't change the font of the document) with LuaTeX (XeTeX wasn't working for some reason. I am not very good at error diagnosis in different engines. I have only practiced pdflatex for most years). Numbers are indeed supported. I think though that double stroke omega isn't supported. I looked here The above solution with bboldx is working in xetex with some small changes in the code.
